# Facebook Javascript SDK: send dialogue redirect_uri not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working with the FB Javascript send dialogue. I am wanting the iframe/popup to redirect to another url so I can mark that the FB message has been sent. However `redirect_uri` doesn't seem to be working.

```
<script>  
function test(){    
FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxx', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    //call dialog her
  FB.ui({

      method: 'send',
      link: 'http://www.google.com',
      redirect_uri: 'google.com',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
      redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:4567/home'


          });

    });

 }

 </script>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?